# SQL Multiple WHERE Columns combined with LIKE

Tags: sql, multiple-columns, sql-like

after searching through the whole www I finally ended up here with a question and hopefully more capable responders than I am.

I am trying to implement a **full text search** on my webpage. 
The Sql query works with **one WHERE** condition but not with several. Unfortunately I have no clue how to solve my problem with the help of EXIST / IN / INNER JOIN or other Operators.
Code which works:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM artikel WHERE author LIKE '$suchtext' LIMIT $offset, $no_of_abs";
```

Code which doesnt work:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM artikel WHERE (author OR shorty OR vollartikel) LIKE '%$suchtext%' LIMIT $offset, $no_of_abs";
```

The variable $suchtext is correctly passed and received through jquery $ajax POST and my php script.

Example goal:

```
author  |   volltext  |  shorty
--------+-------------+---------
tulum   |   tul       |  asf
rae     |   zutotu    |  vizetu
```

$suchtext is "tu"
Results: 2
Row1 & Row2

I appreciate any answers.

**Solution:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM artikel WHERE author LIKE '%$suchtext%' OR shorty LIKE '%$suchtext%' OR vollartikel LIKE '%$suchtext%' LIMIT $offset, $no_of_abs";
```

Comment: The syntax is wrong. Change to: `WHERE author LIKE '%$suchtext%' OR shorty LIKE '%$suchtext%' OR vollartikel LIKE '%$suchtext%'`

Comment: Thank you !!, I tried this but with a "WHERE" between every OR .. :D

Comment: `(author OR shorty OR vollartikel)` isn't even valid SQL - which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE` is a binary operator that takes two strings.  `OR` is a boolean operator that operates on boolean values.

You need to explicitly list this out:

```
(author LIKE ? OR
 shorty LIKE ? OR
 vollartikel LIKE ?
)
```

Note that this uses `?` as a parameter placeholder.  Use parameters when constructing SQL queries in applications.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but the " ( ) " isnt necessary! :)

Comment: @dogma . . . I added the parens in case you have additional conditions you want to check.